# How to handle click of a feature?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps has a list of bus stops, I don't. So I instead of adding markers for bus stops, I want to use Google Maps own bus stops. How do I handle click of their bus stops?

Comment: When I click on a bus-stop-icon in a V3-map nothing happens, what do you want to "handle"?

Comment: In my city's bus stops it does show a window. I want to show my own, like one would do with a marker.

Comment: It is a place of type bus_station. Can I control places as if they were markers?

Comment: There appears an InfoWindow for you when you click on a bus-icon in http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/dT84b/ ? For me nothing happens.

Comment: You are right, right now nothing opens for bus stops. How can I open a InfoWindow when I click the bus stop?

Comment: You are not able to determine if the click happens on a bus-stop, it's just an image and when you click on it the only detail you may get is the coordinate of the click(it's the same as when you e.g. click on a street, you may get the coordinate, but you may not get the information that the click has been on a street)

Comment: dont mix up the maps-API and [**google-maps**](http://maps.google.com). There opens an Window when you click on a bus-stop on maps.google.com because google has the data, but these data usually are not free to use. Google may have the license to use these data on maps.google.com, this must not mean that they have the license to offer the data to a another(e.g. users of a maps-API-implementation)

Comment: Well, if that is true, that kind of answers my question, unfortunately.